# Jssor slider - slide duration

Tags: jssor

I have taken over a project that utilises the Jssor slider control. It works great, and I've managed to solve all but one of the issues I have with it - hopefully this is a simple one!

What I want to do is adjust the amount of time before a new image slides into the frame. I'm confused by this because it looks to be simple according to the instructions - but they don't seem to work for me.

Right now, the control is rotating images automatically. However, my JavaScript code is as follows:

```
var options = {
  $AutoPlay: false,
  $AutoPlaySteps: 1,
  $Idle: 3000,
  $PauseOnHover: 0,
```

As you'll see, the 'autoplay' setting as 'false'. I've tried changing it to 'true' and adjecting the 'AutoPlayInterval' setting, but it makes no difference to the performance of the control.

I suspect I'm mssing something blindingly obvious, but I can't see it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
$AutoPlay: true,                                    //[Optional] Whether to auto play, to enable slideshow, this option must be set to true, default value is false
     $AutoPlayInterval: 6000,                            //[Optional] Interval (in milliseconds) to go for next slide since the previous stopped if the slider is auto playing, default value is 3000
     $PauseOnHover: 1,                                   //[Optional] Whether to pause when mouse over if a slider is auto playing, 0 no pause, 1 pause for desktop, 2 pause for touch device, 3 pause for desktop and touch device, default value is 1

      $ArrowKeyNavigation: true,                        //[Optional] Allows keyboard (arrow key) navigation or not, default value is false
     $SlideDuration: 6000,
```

Answer (score 0):

The $SlideDuration (in milliseconds, default value is 500) option indicates the duration to swipe slide left <-> right.